# JSON restful service security

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, backend, frontend

I am currently building a web application, that has fully separated a "frontend" server with Lighttpd only serving the index.html and javascript etc.

Backbone.js etc. keep my frontend in connection with my webservice "backend" written in Node.js

The backend is completely stateless, doing authentication each request through http basic and runs SSL (https).

How do I make sure that only the connections happening on my "backend" server are comming from the Lighttpd "frontend" server and not some random hacker?

Thanks for help.

Comment: How would a hacker authenficate over SSL?

Comment: So does the Browser talk directly to your Node server? Or are their REST queries proxied through your Lighttpd server?

Comment: Browser talks to the Node.js server directly, the Node.js server is a REST JSON service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the front-end server is going to be on a specific IP address or range or IP addresses, you might want to restrict traffic on the back-end server to only be from that address.

Answer (score 1):

You may use ssl between the 2 servers and use a certificate to ensure identification. That's really secure if you protect your certificate well.